# Android Studio parou de funcionar depois de instalar o Flutter e da esta infirmmação de erro

Tags: javascript, java, android-studio, flutter, java-8

Bom dia!

Tinha o Android Studio instalado na minha maquina e depois de instalar o Flutter o mesmo parou de funcionar.
Desinstalei o Flutter e mesmo assim o Android Studio não que funcionar e só apresenta esta mensagem de erro:

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.picocontainer.PicoRegistrationException: Key io.flutter.settings.FlutterSettings duplicated
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:280)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:618)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:591)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$initApplication$2.accept(ApplicationLoader.kt:379)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$initApplication$2.accept(ApplicationLoader.kt)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenCompleteStage(CompletableFuture.java:792)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:2153)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:110)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.initApplication(ApplicationLoader.kt:376)
    at com.a.c.c.d.aw.a(aw.java:65)
    at com.a.c.c.d.aY.a(aY.java:98)
    at com.a.c.c.d.a1.b(a1.java:260)
    at com.a.c.c.d.a1.a(a1.java:122)
    at com.a.c.c.d.aC.a(aC.java:56)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:19)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:303)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:245)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:47)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.picocontainer.PicoRegistrationException: Key io.flutter.settings.FlutterSettings duplicated
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.registerComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:119)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerServices(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:320)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:186)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:157)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$registerAppComponents$1.apply(ApplicationLoader.kt:93)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$registerAppComponents$1.apply(ApplicationLoader.kt)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:616)
    ... 20 more

-----
JRE 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64 by JetBrains s.r.o
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre
```

Como resolver?

Att: Luciano.vtn

Comment: Bom dia!  Resolvido ; obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Tive um problema parecido, e com a desinstalação de primeiro momento não resolveu. Solucionei removendo completamente os arquivos do Android Studio. Pode seguir os passos deste [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10) para remover totalmente.
Observação: faça um **backup** dos seus projetos existentes no Android Studio.

**Passo 1: Bakcup dos projetos do Android Studio:**

Vá na pasta `%USERPROFILE%\AndroidStudioProjects`copie os arquivos e salve em um diretório de sua preferencia, pois é aqui que os projetos são salvos por padrão no Andriod Studio.

**Passo 2: Rode o desinstalador do Android Studio**

Abra o **Painel de Controle**, vá em **Programas** selecione **Desinstalar um Programa**. Depois, clique em "Android Studio" e **Desinstalar**.

**Passo 3: Remover os arquivos do Andriod Studio**

Para remover qualquer arquivo de configuração remanescente, no Explorador de Arquivos, navegue até sua pasta de usuário (`%USERPROFILE%`), e exclua `.android`, `.AndroidStudio` e qualquer diretório que faça referência a versão, por exemplo, `.AndroidStudio1.2`, e também `.gradle` e `.m2` caso existam.

Depois vá até `%APPDATA%` e exclua o diretório `JetBrains`.

Então, vá em `C:\Program Files` e exclua o diretório `Android`.

**Passo 4: Remover SDK**

Para remover qualquer arquivo remanescente do SDK, vá até `%LOCALAPPDATA%` e exclua o diretório `Android`.

Comment: Seria interessante se você mostrasse os passos aqui na sua resposta. Links não são muito aconselhados pois podem parar de funcionar, ou até mesmo a pergunta, a qual o link pertence, ser excluída.

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro desculpe a demora. Fiz a edição listando o passo a passo.